# linux kernel module linker warnings: "*** Warning: <function> [<module>] undefined!" - any way to get rid of them?

Tags: c++, linux, kernel-module, compiler-errors

While compiling Linux kernel modules that depend on each other, linker gives undefined symbol warnings like

```
 Building modules, stage 2.
 MODPOST
*** Warning: "function_name1" [module_name] undefined!
*** Warning: "function_name2" [module_name] undefined!
*** Warning: "function_name3" [module_name] undefined!
```

The unresolved symbols are resolved as soon as module is inserted into kernel using insmod or modprobe. Is there any way to get rid of the linker warning, though?

I have read through 3 Google SERP's on this issue - it seems nobody knows the answer. Are these linker warnings supposed to be this way when you build a kernel module?

Answer (score 16):

Use KBUILD_EXTRA_SYMBOLS as below:
KBUILD_EXTRA_SYMBOLS='your module path'/Module.symvers

Comment: This is the right way. Documentation/kbuild/modules.txt in the linux kernel source tree is the source to go to for this info.

Comment: +1. In a related move, make abolutely sure that if you've rebuilt the kernel (even with no changes), do a make modules afterwards to keep the symvers in sync. Otherwise you get this error.

Answer (score 9):

Finally, I got it. Thanks to shodanex for putting me on the right track.

***Update:*** Be very careful when applying this fix to builds for older versions of kernel, as there is a bug in **Makefile.modpost** file in older versions of the kernel which makes your build misbehave and build wrong targets when you specify **KBUILD_EXTMOD** option.

You have to specify the paths to the source of the modules you depend on in **KBUILD_EXTMOD** make parameter.

Say, you have a module **foo** that depends on symbols from module **bar**.

Source files for **foo** are in **foo/module/** and source files for bar are in **bar/module/**

The make command in **Makefile** for **foo** probably looks like

```
make ARCH=$$ARCH CROSS_COMPILE=$$CROSS_COMPILE -C $$LINUX_DIR \
    M=`pwd`/module \
    modules
```

(the exact line may differ in your project).

Change it to

```
make ARCH=$$ARCH CROSS_COMPILE=$$CROSS_COMPILE -C $$LINUX_DIR \
    M=`pwd`/module \
    KBUILD_EXTMOD=`pwd`/../bar/module \
    modules
```

(we added the KBUILD_EXTMOD=`pwd`/../bar/module \      line, where `pwd`/../bar/module is a path to sources of kernel module we depend on.

One would expect **KBUILD_EXTRA_SYMBOLS** parameter to work this way, however it's **KBUILD_EXTMOD**.

Comment: from which version of linux does this start to work? i tried to use this method on 2.6.12 kernel building external modules, but to no avail, it only build to bar modules, totally ignore the foo module, any help?

Comment: KBUILD_EXTMOD is synonymous with M (and SUBDIRS) which is why it builds the bar module. Use KBUILD_EXTRA_SYMBOLS as per sinojs reply.

Answer (score 3):

No they are not. Wheter you build your code in-tree or out of tree, this message should not be displayed.I think you should fix your Makefile. Here is an example makefile. Not perfect, but used to work (until 2.6.26, did not try it since) :

```
ifneq ($(KERNELRELEASE),)
# We were called by kbuild

obj-m += mymodule.o 
mymodule-objs := mymodule_usb.o a.o b.o c.o

else  # We were called from command line

KDIR := /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build
PWD  := $(shell pwd)

default:
    @echo '    Building FOO drivers for 2.6 kernel.'
    @echo '    PLEASE IGNORE THE "Overriding SUBDIRS" WARNING'
    $(MAKE) -C $(KDIR) SUBDIRS=$(PWD) modules

install:
    ./do_install.sh *.ko

endif  # End kbuild check

clean:
    rm -f -r *.o *.ko .*cmd .tmp* core *.i
```

For further documentation, you can check the kernel tree, the kbuild process is [documented](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v2.6.28.7/Documentation/kbuild/modules.txt)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Any idea how exactly?

Comment: I'm sorry, but it doesn't really work. The warnings are still there.
Also, the @echo '    PLEASE IGNORE THE "Overriding SUBDIRS" WARNING' troubles me. I could use the same approach to echo 'PLEASE IGNORE the [module_name] undefined!' warning, but obviously this is not the way I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Related to the above technique of using KBUILD_EXTMOD, and the question of which kernel versions it works under:

- andycjw indicated it didn't work for him in 2.6.12
- It didn't work for me in 2.6.15 (broke my module build)
- Looking through the kernel commits, I see a number of changes to Makefile.modpost that seem related in 2.6.26 and 2.6.28, so I expect one of those is the limit.

Answer (score 0):

My need to be tailored to your tree.
In our source we created a SYMBOLSDIR that is a path to all the modules

SYMBOLSDIR = 'some path'

make (same as above example) $(KERNELDIR) MODVERDIR=$(SYMBOLSDIR) modules